# Calculation wrong after multiple create class

Tags: android

I have used the code below to calculate the value of linear weighted moving average but when I tried to recalculate for a new set of data by create a new class the result was wrong.

The first call I got value correctly but for the second call it was wrong.

```
public class LWMA
{
BarChart barChart;
int maPeriod;
public double value[];

public LWMA(int mp,BarChart bc){
    barChart = bc;
    maPeriod = mp;

    value = new double[barChart.barCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < barChart.barCount - 1; i++){
        value[i] = 0;
    }
    calculateIndicator();
}   // Ending L

public boolean calculateIndicator(){
    double sumPrice;
    double sumDivider;
    sumPrice = 0;
    sumDivider = 0;

    for ( int i = 1; i <= maPeriod; i++) 
        sumDivider += i;

    for (int i = 0; i < barChart.barCount; i++){
        value[i] = 0f;
        if (i >= maPeriod){
            sumPrice = 0f;
            for (int j = 0; j < maPeriod; j++){
                sumPrice += (barChart.barChartItem[i-j].getClosePrice()*(maPeriod-j));
            }   // loop j
            value[i] = sumPrice/sumDivider;
        }
        else{
            value[i] = 0f;
        }
    }   //loop i
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Should we guess what data you used?

Comment: @APlus , Please post the inputs that you used, what your actual output was, and what you expected it to be.

Comment: I'm sorry about my lack of explanation. I used data from the closing price which declare of double type data. BarChart stored array of class BarChartItem that hold the data that read from a file on device.

Comment: I used the same in the second call. The output was wrong. Anyway how can I add the image on the comment.